# Laravel, can't build query for array in multiple <select>

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-query-builder, laravel-filters

### I made a filter to find businesses

There are **several cities** to choose from

[image]

Cities store on **city_id** column

The filter looks like this

```
<select id="city" multiple name="city[]">
  @foreach($cities as $city)
    <option value="{{ $city->name }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

All request

```
dd($request->all())
```

shows me this

[image]

I build query for franchise or business
like this

```
if ($request->has('fb')) {
  $businessesQuery->where('fb', $request->fb);
}
```

I try to build query like this but it's not works

```
if ($request->has('city[]')) {
    $typeArray = explode(",", $request->city[]);
    $businessesQuery->whereIn('city_id', $typeArray);
}
```

**Help me solve this issue, I would be very grateful!**

Comment: You should be able to do just: `->whereIn('city_id', $request->city)` since [whereIn() accepts arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` must use `city_id` as a value and not the city name. Because you're trying to search using the `id` not `name`.

```
    <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
```

`explode` function takes a `string` as in input and returns an array. In your case your `city[]` request value is already an array visible from the `dump`. You should use it directly. Something like this.

```
if ($request->has('city')) {
    $businessesQuery->whereIn('city_id', $request->input('city');
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that it should be: `input('city')` and not `input('city[]')`. When adding `[]` to an input name, PHP will simply store it in the name (without the `[]`) but as an array.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you're right. Thanks! I will update my answer.